# Java Timer : Cancel all the missed exections

Tags: java, timertask

I am using

```
scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, Date firstTime, long period)
```

in my program. If the start time is already passed, all the tasks that were missed between the start time and current time are executed. As the documentation says:

As a consequence of the above, if the scheduled first time is in the past, then any "missed" executions will be scheduled for immediate "catch up" execution.

Is there any way to stop these "catch up" executions?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you can do is to use the `schedule` call instead:

```
schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)
```

And beforehand calculate the delay required for the first task to start. If the desired start time has already passed simply use a delay of 0. Like this:

```
long delay = startTime.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis();
delay = delay < 0 ? 0 : delay;
```